# Hash in an url inputed to \href inside \cite

Tags: biblatex, citing, urls

I'm using `biblatex` and `hyperref`. If I type `\href{<url>}{<name>}` where the url contains a `#`, I get the desired result, but if I type `\cite[\href{<url>}{<name>}]{<label>}` (again with `#` ⊂ `<url>`) I get an error. What's happening? Here's a MWE:

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nty]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{qui,
    author = {Cervantes, Miguel de},
    title = {Don Quijote de la Mancha},
    publisher = {Ediciones Bruguera},
    year = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite[\href{https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Quijote_de_la_Mancha#El_lugar_de_La_Mancha}{wiki}]{qui}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if one adds `\` before `#` in the url everything works fine, as in `\cite[\href{https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Quijote_de_la_Mancha\#El_lugar_de_La_Mancha}{wiki}]{qui}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off pursuing a different approach than the one given in [your own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698714/5001): (a) provide an `url` field inside the bibliographic entry, (b) load the `xurl` package to allow linebreaks at arbitrary points in a long URL string, and (c) use an ordinary `\cite` directive, i.e., one *without* an optional argument that contains an `\href` directive. That way, you never have to concern yourself with having to escape various TeX-special characters such as `#`.

[image]

Obviously, you're free to make different color choices for `citecolor` and `urlcolor` than the ones made in the example code presented below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@book{qui,
    author = {Miguel de Cervantes},
    title  = {Don Quijote de la Mancha},
    publisher = {Ediciones Bruguera},
    year   = {2001},
    url    = {https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Quijote_de_la_Mancha#El_lugar_de_La_Mancha}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{qui}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually needed to get the url inside the \cite (the Quijote example was made up), but thank you anyway ^^.